# How i put together two functions, both with a recursion inside

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures

I am a beginner and this my first post here(plus I'm not a native English speaker), so please forgive me if my code and/or my English are bad.Given two numbers I want to write a JavaScript function to find if the second one is a power of the first one, and then determine that power (ex: 2,8 the output must be 3). I wrote two functions, both working, but I can't put them together.

This is the first one to check if the second number is a power of the first one.

```
function checkNumbers(x,y){
  if (y%x !==0){
    return "this numbers are not valid"
  }
  else if(x===y) {
     return "correct!"
  }
  else { 
    y=y/x
    return checkNumbers(x,y)
  }  
}

checkNumbers(2,8)   // will give the first answer
checkNumbers(2,18)  // will give the second answer
```

The second function will give you the integral logarithm:

```
count =1;

function findGrade(x,y) {
  if(y/x===1)
    return "the grade is " + count;

  count++;
  y = y/x;
  return findGrade(x,y)
}

findGrade(2,8)  // output 3
findGrade(2,16) // output 4
```

How can I put them together into one function? I think i need a closure, but I didn't find the way to make that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, in fact, pretty simple.

You could do the following:

```
function findGrade(x, y, count = 1) {
    // If the numbers are not valid, throw an error. The execution is interrupted.
    if(y % x != 0) throw "Invalid inputs";

    // If the inputs are different, continue the execution and add 1 to count.
    if(x != y) return findGrade(x, y/x, ++count);

    // If none of the above are true, you have your result!
    return count;
}
```

Tests:

```
console.log(findGrade(2, 8));        // Outputs 3
console.log(findGrade(2, 16));       // Outputs 4
console.log(findGrade(2, 3));        // Error: Invalid inputs
console.log(findGrade(3, 3486784401));  // Outputs 20
```

Please let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: oh great, this is perfect and very easier that what i've tried to do. You've taught me a lot with, thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome :) Please, don't forget to chose the best answer to your question! @amedeo

Answer (score 1):

`checkNumbers` should return a Boolean value, not a message.  Then findGrade can check that result to see whether it should compute the logarithm.  Something like this:

```
function checkNumbers(x,y){
  if (y%x !==0){
    return false
  }
  else if(x===y) {
     return true
  }
  // the rest of your function remains the same.

function findGrade(x,y) {
  // First, check to see whether y is a power of x
  if checkNumbers(x,y) {
    // your original findGrade function goes here
  }
  else
    return -1;  // Use this as a failure code.
```

Does this work for you?

Another possibility is to combine the functions entirely: *try* to find the logarithm (what you call "grade"); if it works, you get your answer; if it fails (at `y%x !== 0`), then you report the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my method is different, but I have implemented it below. In real world application I would do some more typechecking on inputs and check if there is a third argument: if not default to 0 (First Iteration default the count to 0), but this is the general idea. You can run the snippet below.

```js
// Arguments 
// 1: Base of Exponent
// 2: test Number
// 3: count by reference

function checkPower (base, test, count) {
  let division = test/base
  // base case
  if (division === 1) {
    count++
    return count
  } else if (division < 1) {
    console.log("not a power")
    return;
  }
  // iteration step
  count++
  return checkPower(base, division, count++)
}

// Test Cases

let test = checkPower(2, 32, 0)
if (test) {
  console.log(test) // 5
}

test = checkPower(2, 1024, 0)
if (test) {
  console.log(test) // 10
}

test = checkPower(2, 9, 0)
if (test) {
  console.log(test) // "not a power"
}
```